# User-defined type declaring explicitly a nested type

Tags: python, python-3.7, mypy

I find it really useful to have Python types such as `Dict[str, int]`, which declare the types they contain and allow them to be type checked too. However I can't find how I can create such a type. If, for example, I write

```py
    class Classy:
       def __init__(self, x: Any) -> None:
           self.value = x
```

how can I express it as `Classy[int]`, `Classy[str]`, `Classy[List[int]]`, etc?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TypeVar()` to declare type variable, and use `Generic` as base class.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
T = TypeVar('T')
class Classy(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
        self.value = x
    def get_value(self) -> T:
        return self.value
```

You can try:

```
class1 = Classy[int](100)
class2 = Classy[str]('abc')
print(class1.get_value())
print(class2.get_value())
```

Then you will see:

```
100
abc
```